# Dynamic Size for NSCollectionViewItem

Tags: swift, macos, nslayoutconstraint, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I am trying to give a dynamic size to my NSCollectionViewItem. I want them to have a size determine by their content and the constraint I defined.

For that I have add to my viewcontroller which holds the NSCollectionView the following :

```
extension ViewController :  NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSSize{

        let item = collectionView.item(at: indexPath)
        if let viewItem = item as NSCollectionViewItem? {
            return viewItem.view.fittingSize
        }

        return NSSize(width: 200, height: 100)

    }
}
```

Which throw an exception.

```
An uncaught exception was raised
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
```

I don't see where it come from, I tried to catch it but xcode says that `item(at:)` don't throws exception.

Edit: but in fact it does, I had an exception breakpoint and it break in `item(at:)` [image: item(at:) exception]

Beside sending a bug repport to Apple does someone have an other idea ? 
And since item(at:) is not supposed to throw error a do catch bloc is ineffective

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286020/nscollectionview-sizeforitemat-always-returning-exception-when-trying-to-referen/59319607#59319607

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, I Don't think this method is crashing.
From the documentation:

> *Return:* The item for the specified index path or nil if no item is available.

Have you try to [add an exception breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802723/2003734)? You should see where it's crashing.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeForItemAtIndexPath` calling before creating a `UICollectionViewItem`, so it's impossible to do it.